# How to find and call to the phone number from webview content?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, ios7, uiwebview

I am having a webview content displaying in webview. In that content how do i find the tapped link is a Phone number or not. If it is a phone number i want make a call to that phone number.How to achieve this programmatically in ios 6.0 and above.

Comment: There is a property on the webview Detection - Phone numbers. You can set it in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just looking for detecting a phone number in webview's content, you can set the property in code:

```
@property(nonatomic) UIDataDetectorTypes dataDetectorTypes

self.webView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber;
```

Any detected phone number in the content will then be blue and underlined and tapping them will present a choice to call to that number.

Comment: Thanks Martin.On selection of that phone link i need to make a call.How to do that ?

Comment: You don't do it, the system does it for you. When you tap on the link and your phone is capable of making a call, you are presented with a dialog where you either Cancel or Call.